# Kafka Connect with Elasticsearch in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I am trying to connect Kafka(MSK) in aws to Elasticsearch in aws. I set it up but currently getting an   error.Here are the steps:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-install java-1.8.0  
wget https://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.2/confluent-5.2.0-2.11.tar.gz?_ga=2.30447679.1453070970.1611201478-474568264.1611201478 
tar -xf confluent-5.2.0-2.11.tar.gz 
confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch:11.0.0
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/confluent-5.2.0/bin:${PATH};
```

I then updated the connect-standalone.properties config file:

```
bootstrap.servers=b-1.xx.xx.c8.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092
        
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
        
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
        
plugin.path=share/java,/home/ubuntu/confluent-5.2.0/share/confluent-hub-components
```

Then I created another config file for the sink connector.

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=sampleTopic
topic.index.map=logs:logs_index
connection.url=https://xxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443
type.name=log
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

Then I run the confluent standalone command to connect.

```
bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties etc/kafka/elasticsearch-connect.properties
```

It runs but then eventually throws an error which I can not figure out why. Bellow is the error:

```
ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:119)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef$CaseInsensitiveValidString
```

Any help or input would be great thank you.

Comment: If you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which aws resource is rejecting the network traffic. For VPC flow logs information please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) document from AWS

Comment: You think this error is an error when trying to connect from kafka to elastic search?

Comment: Your `CLASSPATH` is misconfigured when you run `connect-standalone`... Try at least removing `share/java` from the `plugin.path` in the connector properties... Also, you can install confluent-hub on its own, then get the connector; you dont need the entire Confuent Platform

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the same error. Could the error have to do with something in the config file for Elasticsearch connector? Elasticsearch is in AWS not sure if that matters at all. Any other help would be great.